# I want to know which is the best 'C' compiler for Windows 7?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, windows-7

I'm using dev c++ but it has creating some problems while working with windows 7

So want the best compiler which is works with windows 7.

By best I mean whiich will give me the best performance.

Comment: Don't say "what's the best"; say "which ones fit these criteria" and then list the criteria that are important to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

well, there are many to choose from:

- [Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/default), works 'best' with MS
  OSes
- [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) or [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) with
  [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), works 'best' with standard
  C99 code
- [Pelles C](http://www.smorgasbordet.com/pellesc/) works best at being simple

Your choice really boils down to what you require and what your working with, so just look at the above examples, pick what suites you best

Comment: Especially the debugger (ok, it's not a compiler) of VisualStudio is the best I've ever worked with...

Comment: @eckes: as a visual debugger it looks great, though I avoid it as I prefer ollydbg with all its fancy plugins :P (though really I've run into situations where the VS debugger fails horribly, but olly has never let me down)

Comment: @Necrolis : So, how does ollydbg hold up when debugging an x64 app? Or on an x64 OS? ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn: its a 32bit debugger :P but thats what IDA x64 or windbg x64 are for, at least till oleh gets ollydbg2 x64 done :) as for running it on a 64bit OS, runs great for me :), only have one problem and thats starting apps inside the debugger (a lot of plugins also don't work, but this is due to the plugin's poor design...), though I'm pretty sure that can be fixed (ollydbg2 doesn't have this problem, but it doesn't have plugin support yet :<).

Comment: @Necrolis : I, personally, cannot wait for olly v2. Unfortunately, I've been saying that for 5 years now. ;-[

Comment: @ildjarn: well hes gotten the core redone now, so there is a new release every 2-3 months, instead of every 1-2 years :) but when once he has plugins in, I think people aren't gonna care too much about any other features, except maybe the x64 version, which is probably why he is delaying their addition. I actually check his page every day in case of an update :D

Answer (score 4):

Dev c++ is garbage. It is not a compiler BTW.

On Windows use MinGW (with Code::Blocks IDE) or MSVC++2010

Comment: Code::Blocks is slow on my Vista machine; it takes years to start up. But +1 for MSVC++2010.

Comment: uh... whut? As far as I know DevC++ uses mingw as a compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You can try borland c++ (with turbo C++ ide..) its pretty old but works fine... :)
or blodshed dev c++ is also goood..

Comment: *Yeah full screen wouldn't work in turbo c++

Answer (score -3):

I suggest you install a cygwin and using gcc. 
This is a good for leaner.

ANything better? Yeah, I sgguest you install an Ubuntu as dual system.
That's real programmer do.

Comment: While I develop in Ubuntu that's because I develop for Linux system, not much help for someone asking to develop on Windows 7